# How to solve the following error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, ip, windows-server-2016

I have created one instance at Amazon Lightsail where Platform is Linux/Unix and choose Wordpress as an application. Using this Wordpress, I have designed one website and it is running using Lightsail instance IP[xx.xx.xx.xx]. I have created another instance at Amazon lightsail in Windows server 2016. I have installed Geoserver 2.11.0 in this server, where Tomcat 8.0 is working as server let. Some vector Layers I have added at Geoserver. In my WordPress website, I have added Google Map. Now I want to fetch those layers on to Google map. This is my actual target point.
When I was trying to access Geoserver using windows server 2016's IP address [except local host], that means when I will provide the IP [xx.xx.5.124] in the browser , it will open the Geoserver login page. But when I am providing it in the browser, it is giving the following error.
How could I solve it?

"Could Not Connect
Description: Could not connect to the requested server host."

Comment: You'll need to do some diagnostics to work out why the servers can't connect. Not really sure about Lightsail, assume it's similar to full AWS. Is your security group / firewall open? Can you connect to that same resource from your home PC?

Comment: I have off the firewall & I have activated aws firewall manager. But it is giving same error. I could not find out the reason. No I am not able to connect using my PC. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately there are too many things this could be. You're going to have to use a process of elimination. Try to connect to the service from itself on the server. Then try a server in the same network. Then a server in another AWS network.